# How to find the roots to the polynomial $z^3+z^2+iz^2-z+1+3i$

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-equations

I'm having a bit of a problem on how to compute forward the values for z from this equation:

$$
z^3+z^2+iz^2-z+1+3i=0 
$$

In the question there's given that one solution or root is z=i, by solving by polynomial division I get the equation
$$
\begin{align}
&z^2+z+2iz+i-3=0 \\
\iff & z^2+(1+2i)z+i-3=0\\
\iff &\left(z+\frac{1+2i}{2}\right)^2=z^2+(1+2i)z+\left(\frac{1+2i}{2}\right)^2. 
\end{align}
$$
I substitute this expression with $w$.
$$
\begin{align} 
&w^2-\left(\frac{1+2i}{2}\right)^2+i-3=0\\
\iff &\left(\frac{1+2i}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}+i+i^2=\frac{1}{4}+i-1\\ 
\iff & \left(-\frac{3}{4}+i\right)w^2-\left(\frac{3}{4}+i\right)+i-3\\
\iff &w^2+\frac{3}{4}-3=w^2=\frac{9}{4}\\
\end{align}
$$
But it's from here where it struggles with me with the second degree equation for some reason. Could anyone explain how it should be done, I would really appreciate it, any form of trix or so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am pretty sure it can be done by the quadratic formula.

Comment: Yes, it was pretty simple like that, that Bernand pointed out, I just didn't realise it. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have $\;w=\pm\dfrac{3i}2$, so
$$z=-\frac{1+2i}2\pm\frac{3i}2=\cdots$$

*Edit*: As pointed by @WETutorialSchool, The final equation in $w$ is actually
$$w^2=\frac 94,\quad\text{whence}\quad z=-\frac{1+2i}2\pm\frac{3}2=-(2+i),1-i.$$

Comment: I think the final equation should be $w^2-\frac94=0$, not $w^2=-\frac94$.

Comment: You're right. I should have checked. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Thanks for the help! (y)